# Aggregate root and instances creation of child entities

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have an aggregate that includes the entities `A`, `AbstractElement`, `X`, `Y` and `Z`. The root entity is `A` that also has a list of `AbstractElement`. Entities `X`,`Y` and `Z` inherit from `AbstractElement`. I need the possibility to add instances of `X`, `Y` and `Z` to an instance of `A`. One approach is to use one method for each type, i.e. `addX`, `addY` and `addZ`. These methods would take as arguments the values required to create instances of `X`, `Y` and `Z`. But, each time I add a new type that inherits from `AbstractElement`, I need to modify the entity `A`, so I think it's not the best solution.

Another approach is to use an abstract add method `addAbstractElement` for adding `AbstractElement` instances. But, in this case, the method would take as argument an instance of `AbstractElement`. Because this method would be called by entities located outside of the aggregate, following DDD rules/recommandations, are these external entities authorized to create instances of `AbstractElement`? I read in the Eric Evans book that external entities are not authorized to hold references of entities of an aggregate other than the root?

What is the best practice for this kind of problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Evan's book, page 139:

"if you needed to add elements inside a preexisting AGGREGATE, you might create a FACTORY METHOD on the root of the AGGREGATE"

Meaning, you should create a factory method on the root (A) which will get the AbstractElement's details. This method will create the AbstractElement (X/Y/Z) according to some decision parameter and will add it to its internal collection of AbstractElements. In the end this method return the id of the new element.

Best Regards,

[Itzik Saban](http://itziksaban.blogspot.com/)

Comment: In my case, the details are different from one entity to another. To create an instance of X, I need one string. To create an instance of Y, I need two strings... How it works in this case? How can I use only one method?

Comment: You are not restricted by DDD to create only one method - you can create 3 different methods as long as they act as FACTORY METHODS.

Comment: But in this case, the problem I raised in my question still exists. I would need to add a new factory method each time a new type is added.

Comment: And if you wouldn't use DDD, could you avoid adding new constructor/factory method each time a new type is added?

Comment: By the way, a factory should only be able to produce an object in consistent state, probably with optional elements still to be added. So maybe the data you need to pass in order to create X/Y/Z is not that diverse. And if so, you won't need one method per each type.

Comment: If I wouldn't use DDD, I would have only one method that takes an AbstractElement. Then, a client code would instantiate the proper element X, Y or Z and would pass it to the method. But, one rule with DDD is that client code should not directly instantiate X, Y, Z. It should add them through a method located in the aggregate root.

Comment: A FACTORY METHOD creates an instance but it may return it rather than adding it to a collection.

Answer (score 2):

A few comments. As the previous answerer said, it's a good practice to use a factory method. If you can avoid it, never create objects out of the blue. Usually, it's a pretty big smell and a missed chance to make more sense out of your domain.

I wrote a small example to illustrate this. Video is in this case the aggregate root. Inside the boundaries of the aggregate are the video object and its associated comments. Comments can be anonymous or can have been written by a known user (to simplify the example, I represented the user by a username but obviously, in a real application, you would have something like a UserId).

Here is the code:

```cs
public class Video {
    private List<Comment> comments;

    void addComment(final Comment.Builder builder) {
        this.comments.add(builder.forVideo(this).build());
        // ...
    }
}


abstract public class Comment {
    private String username;
    private Video video;

    public static public class Builder {
        public Builder anonymous() {
             this.username = null;
             return this;
        }

        public Builder fromUser(final String username) {
             this.username = username;
             return this;
        }

        public Builder withMessage(final String message) {
             this.message = message;
             return this;
        }

        public Builder forVideo(final Video video) {
            this.video = video;
            return this;
        }

        public Comment build() {
             if (username == null) {
                 return new AnonymousComment(message);
             } else {
                 return new UserComment(username, message);
             }
        }
    }
}

public class AnonymousComment extends Comment {
    // ...
}

static public class UserComment extends Comment {
    // ...      
}
```

One thing to ponder on also is that aggregate boundaries contain objects and not classes. As such, it's highly possible that certain classes (mostly value objects but it can be the case of entities also) be represented in many aggregates.